# How to print the last two digits of a 4 digit input taken by the user?

Tags: python

```
# Read an integer:
a = input()
```

Over here I take an Input from the reader or the user who is using my app.....
# Print a value:
print(a[2, 3])
...and then I want to print out only the last two digits
but I am getting an error as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 4, in 
TypeError: string indices must be integers
Example input what I wanted it to be :
1234
Example output what I wanted it to be :
34
Can you please explain me my error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the last two digits you can use `print(a[-2:])` since python uses negative index to start form the last item.
also check if the length of the input is greater than 2 characters.

```
if len(a) >= 2:
    print(a[-2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says: String indices must be integers. You give it a **tuple** (of integers, but it's still a tuple). You should slice it with `a[-2:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
print(a[-2:])
```

This prints the last 2 characters of string a.

Comment: You're still saying it converts.